# WPF Network Recognition

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, networking, network-programming

I'm Developing a local WPF Application for the company that will be installed on each employee's laptop, sometimes employees can take their laptops home, I need to make sure that all the employees can log to the System only from the Company's location (Network) only and not from their homes ... 
how can i do this? ...

I was thinking about getting the Company's Router Mac address using some C# code, but didn't find anything useful ... any suggestions or solutions (with code if possible)

Comment: If you can ping a local resource, its on a local network. For example, if you have a server named "Server01", and you can ping "Server01" (and you can even match IP's if you want), then you can reasonably assume its on the network. Its not 100% fool-proof but it would work. Or you can use a service on a network computer to authenticate log-ins, that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to you:

1) If you not remote access to database or software,I think, you do not need to use the network,Just time in hours limit access to database or software ,you can use such as job in DB and more..

2) Login to wpf app with Active Directory Users.
you can use active directory users to authentication you're wp app and create one account for every employee to access it,you can schedule time to access active directory users to custom time.